# Changing axis limits of effects plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I'm using the effects package to plot interaction effects of a linear regression like this:

```
library(effects)
Model <- lm(drat~hp*cyl, data=mtcars)
plot(effect(term="hp*cyl",mod=Model,default.levels=10),multiline=TRUE)
```

How do I change the limits so that they go from say 0-10? I've tried with ylim=(0,10), and other variations with no effect. Alternatively, can a regression be plotted in the same way using ggplot2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `plot` function, set `ylim` like this

```
plot(effect(term="hp*cyl",mod=Model,default.levels=10),multiline=TRUE,ylim=c(0,10))
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! It's not possible to directly convert the graph obtained with the plot function in ggplot. You need to build the ggplot graph based on the output of the effect function. .

Answer (score 3):

And here is the `ggplot2` version:

```
library(effects)
library(ggplot2)
Model <- lm(drat~hp*cyl, data=mtcars)
ef <- effect(term = "hp:cyl", Model, default.levels = 9) # 9 because the breaks are nicer
ef2 <- as.data.frame(ef)

ggplot(ef2, aes(hp, fit, col = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(y = 'drat') +
  ylim(0, 10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`ggplot2` doesn't know how to deal with an data of class 'eff', so you need to convert your effects data into a dataframe before plotting. You can then use `group=` with your data inside `aes()` to get lines for each group.

```
library(effects)
library(ggplot2)
Model <- lm(drat~hp*cyl, data=mtcars)
e<-effect(term="hp*cyl",mod=Model,default.levels=10)
ee<-data.frame(e)
ee$cyl<-factor(ee$cyl)
ggplot(ee, aes(x = hp, y = fit, group = cyl, colour = cyl)) +
       geom_line() +
       scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,10))
```

[image: ggplot effects plot]

Comment: Grouping is automatic when mapping an aesthetic like color to a factor :) Also, you code should give 10 lines, but your plot only has 5?

Comment: Why should my code give 10 lines? There are only 5 groups to plot within ee$cyl, and looks like the OP's original plot.

Comment: Because `default.levels=10`, so it is calculating `cyl` at ten levels? Running your exact code (and OP's) gives me 10 lines.

Comment: That's so strange, when I run your code below, I still only get 5 groups..

Comment: Don't know what's going on, but my output makes more sense to me.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! The ggplot addition is really helpful